# Dynamic static resource in custom visualforce email template

Tags: visualforce, email-template, force.com-sites, static-resources, urlfor

**Background**

I am trying to add a dynamic link in a visualforce email template to download a PDF which is stored as a publicly available Static Resource:

```
<a href="https://x.cs.force.com/site/{!URLFOR(relatedTo.Static_Resource_Name__c)}">Download PDF</a>
```

But it doesn't generate a valid URL:

```
https://x.cs.force.com/site/resource_name?isdtp=p1
```

**Question**

1. Is it possible to set `URLFOR` dynamically?
2. How can I create a link which has a dynamically generated link to different static resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible with this URL:

```
<a href="https://x.cs.force.com/site/resource/{!relatedTo.Static_Resource_Name__c}">Download PDF</a>
```